# How to spread one column into two based on ID

Tags: r, reshape

I would like to spread one column of my dataframe into two columns based on an ID variable.

My data looks like this

```
df = data.frame(ID = c("M1", "M2", "M2", "M3", "M4", "M4", "M5"),
                Core = c("A", "A","B","B","A","B","A"))

> df
  ID Core
1 M1    A
2 M2    A
3 M2    B
4 M3    B
5 M4    A
6 M4    B
7 M5    A
```

I would like to make the "Core" column into two based on the "ID" so there are no duplicate IDs. I would like it to look like this:

```
  ID CoreA CoreB
1 M1     1     0
2 M2     1     1
3 M3     0     1
4 M4     1     1
5 M5     1     0
```

I'm sure there is an easy solution but I am stumped.

Comment: I'm not sure this wasn't really a request to `reshape` or `spread`. It looks more like a request for a tabulation. If KateN will edit the question to make clear whether there can ever be more than one M1 case associated with CoreA then we will know for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be `spread`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
   mutate(n = 1, Core = str_c("Core", Core)) %>% 
   spread(Core, n, fill = 0)
#   ID CoreA CoreB
#1 M1     1     0
#2 M2     1     1
#3 M3     0     1
#4 M4     1     1
#5 M5     1     0
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df), ID ~ paste0("Core", Core), length)
```